# UISearchBar in place of UINavigationController UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have a `UITableViewController` with a `UISearchDisplayController` (and `UISearchBar`) that is contained in a `UINavigationController` as the root element. Is it possible to configure it so the `UISearchBar` appears in place of the `UINavigationBar`? I don't think hiding the navigation bar will work, a the next screen (pushed on) requires it to be visible (and this will create a  strange animation glitch).

I'm basically going for a screen like the *App Store* search tab.

I've uploaded a sample screenshots of how it looks now:

[image: Default Configuration]
[image: Selected Configuration]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign yourself as the delegate of the UINavigationController and implement `- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated`.

Then use the passed in navigationController to hide the navigation bar.
`[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated]`

**Edit:** Come to think of it, it would be better to pass the animated value into `-setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` as well. Code updated.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution:
You don't need to hide the UINavigationBar, instead, you could merge the UISearchBar into UINavigationBar.

In YourClass.m file:
1. add a UISearchBar property
2. add the UISearchBar into the NavigationItem in the viewDidLoad section.
code:

```
@interface YourClass ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@end

@implementation YourClass
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Reveal cancel button in UISearchBar.
  searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;

  // Add UISearchBar as titleView of the UINavigationBar.
  self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
}
```

last, don't forget to edit your .xib file. Just add the UISearchBar object right down the UINavigationBar and connect the referencing outlets of the UISearchBar to the File's Owner.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can hide your navigationbar by setting the 'navigationBarHidden' property to true.

```
[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

Comment: Then I run into problems when pushing the next view controller (i.e. it has no navigation bar). If I try re-enabling it I get a temporarily blank navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

In the viewDidLoad method of the controller you are pushing

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```