# How to show a UISearchBar from top of screen for table view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I'm looking to duplicate how the Facebook Messenger app shows the UISearchBar. When you tap the leftBarButtonItem in the navigationBar, the UISearchBar appears/animates from the top of the screen down, and when you cancel, it simply disappears upwards where it originated from.

I used to have my UISearchBar as the default setup in my table view's header (in storyboard), but now I'm wanting to do what I stated above but I am not sure where to begin. My search displayer controller is still in my storyboard, but I have deleted the searchBar from the tableView controller in the storyboard.

I appreciate any help offered!

Comment: Just a suggestion - not sure. Maybe you could try adding a subview which appears when you tap the leftBarButtonItem.

Comment: I tried that but the problem is adding the search display's search bar to that subview; it doesn't actually get added.

Comment: possible to post screen shot or sample project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Omitting detail of my own project where I make the same thing it looks as follows:

```
static CGFloat searchBarHeight = 64.0;

@implementation
{
    NSArray *_tableData; // active list of data to show in table at the moment
    NSMutableArray *_filteredContacts; // filtered list while search is active
    NSArray *_allContacts; // initial list of all data without search
    UIView* _searchBarWrapper;
    UIView *_shadowView;
    UISearchBar *_searchBar;
}

- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(showSearchBar:)];

    _searchBarWrapper = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -searchBarHeight, self.navigationController.view.bounds.size.width, searchBarHeight)];
    _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20.0, _searchBarContainer.bounds.size.width, searchBarHeight - 20.0)];
    [_searchBarContainer addSubview:_searchBar];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:_searchBarContainer];

    _shadowView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.navigationController.view.bounds];
    _shadowView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _shadowView.alpha = 0;
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:_shadowView];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideSearchBar:)];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideSearchBar:)];
    [_shadowView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [_shadowView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];

    //_searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_searchBar contentsController:self];
    //_searchController.delegate = self;
    //_searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    //_searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
}

- (void)showSearchBar:(id)sender
{
    [_searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        _searchBarWrapper.center = CGPointMake(_searchBar.center.x, searchBarHeight/2.0);
        _shadowView.alpha = 0.5;
    }];
}

- (void)hideSearchBar:(id)sender
{
    _searchBar.text = nil;
    [_tableView reloadData];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        _searchBarWrapper.center = CGPointMake(_searchBar.center.x, -searchBarHeight/2.0);
        _shadowView.alpha = 0.0;
    }];
    [_searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [_tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    _tableData = _searchBar.isFirstResponder ? _filteredContacts : _allContacts;

    ....................
}


- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (searchText.length) {

        _filteredContacts = ....;

        _shadowView.alpha = 0.0;
        [_tableView reloadData];
    }
    else {
        _shadowView.alpha = 0.5;
    }
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar*)searchBar
{
    [self hideSearchBar:searchBar];
}
```

Note: The general behavior of this construction is analogous to *UISearchDisplayController*, the only difference is that we use the same table to show all results and filtered result. Also we need artificial shadow view.

It was my initial code and its behavior coincides with FB People view controller.
After your comment I wrote standard *UISearchDisplayController* embedding but after commented it out because it breaks desired UI. It is impossible to change its animation behavior.

Comment: Can you please show where your searchBarDisplayController and it's respective search bar code goes?

Comment: Actually you don't even need hideSearchBar. SearchDisplayController does all for hide.

Comment: I will try this later tonight. And don't worry, I will accept your answer if it works for me.

Comment: Please look through my extended answer.

Comment: I can't figure it out, mostly because of the undeclared variable:  _searchBarContainer

Comment: It doesn't look right, the cancel button isn't showing on my search bar. See pic here: http://i.imgur.com/mehx5Cm.png

Comment: You need to set BOOL property to YES to show cancel button in definition of searchbar

Comment: Ok i got that part working, however by setting the tint color and barTintColor properties, the cancel button is not the right color. self.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:16.0/255.0 green:100.0/255.0 blue:230.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:244.0/255.0 green:244.0/255.0 blue:244.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

Comment: I'll write complete settings a bit later

Comment: No problem, you're helping me very much.

Comment: Ok I just figured out how to fix the tint colors myself. The only remaining issue now is that the search bar needs to go down 20 pixels. See pic: http://i.imgur.com/7LvgN6f.png

Comment: It seems that we use different auto layout settings in iOS7. Try to set 40pt offset for searchBar: _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, _searchBarContainer.bounds.size.width, SEARCHBAR_HEIGHT - 40)];

Comment: I figured it out after playing around with the searchBar's layer and blending it in to the view. I will post your bounty in 3 hours or so. Thanks!

Comment: OK hope you've got you wanted!

Answer (score 4):

Check out Apple's [UICatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code. Basically just present your `UISearchController` modally and you get the dropdown animation for free.

Comment: Oh man you are killing it. I'd like to add that setting `definesPresentationContext` to `false` makes the `navigationBar` not animate which looks great.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Facebook hides the navigation bar and displays the Search Bar and Search Display Controller on top. Try hiding the navigation bar with `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];` and presenting your Search Bar and Search Display as a childView of your tableView. (I assume you know how "[Search Bar and Search Display Controller](http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view)" object works)

Another way would be avoiding UITableViewController and adding a UITableView inside a UIViewController and hide the Search Bar under the Navigation Bar so when you hide the Navigation Bar, the Search Bar is visible.

You can also set the UISearchBar as the UINavigationBar's `titleView` as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11150459/1228075).

Comment: Are you sure? Watching carefully, I don't see them hiding the navigation bar.